# How to copy data from another data array at a specified location in swift

Tags: java, arrays, swift, copy, byte

I have 2 data Array.One on them is source and another is destination.I need to copy data from source to destination at a particular index .There is a loop in this which copies the array into destination array and this is how its called                          copyDataOut(byteData, tempBuff, memoryLoc);

I have done in java with the code:

```
private void copyDataOut(byte[] source, byte[] dest, int loc) {
    for (int i = 0; i < dest.length; i++) {
        dest[i] = source[i + loc];
    }
}
```

How do I use something similar in swift.
this is the swift code

copyDataIn(src: finalData, dest: byteData, loc: memoryLoc)// copy the data into the big byte buffer

copyDataIn is a method which should do the copy similar to how its done is java.

Comment: What's your *swift* code? What types do you have? `Array<Int8>`? `Data`? `UnsafeBufferPointer`?

Comment: Why is this tagged with "java"?

Comment: @stefan the OP is asking how to convert from Java to Swift, so they included both tags.

Comment: Thanks Duncan, now I got it.

Comment: I have data array @Alexander-ReinstateMonica.Here is the swift code             copyDataIn(src: finalData, dest: byteData, loc: memoryLoc)

Comment: @min A "data array" isn't a thing. Is it a `Data` or is it an `Array`? What's `finalData` ? What's `byteData`? What's `memoryLoc`? These aren't valid type names.

Answer (score 0):

You just assign a slice using the subscript operator, giving it a range to write over:

```
let source = ["A", "B", "C"]
var dest = (1...10).map(String.init)

dest[5...7] = ArraySlice(source)

print(dest)
```

Comment: My source and dest are byte buffer and how do I use loc in this

Comment: It doesn't matter, any type of array would work just the same. What is `loc`?

Comment: loc is the index where data needs to be copied like the memory location index

Comment: So substitute it for the dummy values of `5` and `7` that I used.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that takes 2 `UnsafeMutableRawBufferPointer`s and a byte count. Then use `copyBytes(from:count:)` to copy the bytes.

See this article for a quick overview of using unsafe buffer pointers in Swift:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/7181017-unsafe-swift-using-pointers-and-interacting-with-c

Comment: how can I specify the location on where to copy to in the destination array when using copyBytes(from:count:)

Answer (score 0):

I got it working like this in swift.Thanks everyone

```
 for i in 0..<finalData.count
            let newData= finalData.count[i]
              byteCardData[i+Loc] = newData

            }
```